# Function for assigning color to raster

Tags: r, plot, colors

I am trying to figure out how create a function in R that I can use to set the color of a cell in a raster when plotted. Eventually I will create a .gif of these plots (I already have that part figured out) with the plotted raster but the colors need to stay consistent plot to plot. i.e. the color assigned to a value of 1 in one plot needs to be the same as the color assigned to a value of 1 in the next plot.

The rasters are (at least right now) in the form of a data frame. For example (I am just using random numbers for the sake of the example but this is how my real data is formatted)

`A<-data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100,value=runif(100, 0, 10000))`

`B<-data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100,value=runif(100, 5, 5300))`

`C<-data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100,value=runif(100, 8500, 12000))`

Now I want to assign a color to some range a values like 1-100, 101-200, etc. so that 1-100 will be plotted as white, then 101-200 as blue etc. Ideally some color ramp from cool to hot colors. Notice that the range of values in A, B, and C are all different. Thats my I need a single function that I can run each data frame that will produce the same colors for the same range of values.

Right now if I plot these three data frames

```
library(ggplot2)
```

`ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=A, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red")`

`ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=B, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red")`

`ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=C, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red")`

The range of colors stays the same but the range of values does not. I need a function that I could run on A, B, and C and get the same "color per value" or "per range of values"

Thanks!

Comment: you could set the limits of the colour scale, and/or the breaks if necessary, `scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red", lim=c(0,2e4))`

Answer (score 1):

My trick is to combine your datasets and create a new column that includes the datasets' names. Then you can create a legend based on those groups (common legend), but create one plot for each dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

A<-data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100,value=runif(100, 0, 10000), name="A")

B<-data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100,value=runif(100, 5, 5300), name="B")

C<-data.frame(x=1:100,y=1:100,value=runif(100, 8500, 12000), name="C")

dt = rbind(A,B,C)

# create 10 groups based on value column (based on general quantiles)
dt = dt %>% mutate(group = ntile(value,10))

# see min and max for each group
dt %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(min= min(value),
                                     max= max(value),
                                     N= n())

# common legend and one plot for each dataset (name)
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=dt, aes(x=x,y=y,fill=group)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue", high="red") +
  facet_grid(~name)
```